# .Net Single Sign on on same domain

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, cookies, single-sign-on

We are trying to create some .Net applications that will run in the same domain.
eg: www.myintrasite.net/myapplication

We need to create a SSO system, we read some articles but what we see is cookie driven solutions.

The problem is that we need to share the session only in Login context.

If we manage the cookies to share the same session, all applications will share the same session keys, but we need to share only one session key, like "id_person".

A simple example is two applications that have a session key named "order_id", with a shared session, the application A will override the session key of application B, that can cause some weird behavious.

There is any solution for a "session context" or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why someone just negativate the question and don't even explain why? Java users...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is going to be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd577079.aspx). It shows you how to set it up properly.

The way I have done it, is set up a "Central Login" that handles all logging in. Then I have multiple applications that are shown once the user is authenticated. I have App 1, App 2 and then App 3. If a user only has access to App 2 then he only sees that app. You will need to place what is mentioned in the link in all of your applications. On my login button click, I placed

> FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(User.Identity.Name.ToString(),
>   false);

This will set the authorization cookie that be used to verify that the user is logged in and can view your other apps. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27576/Single-Sign-on-in-ASP-NET-and-Other-Platforms) is another link will help you as well.

Mine was a bit more complicated than this since I was using Active Directory and Forms Authentication.  Hope this helps you get started.